# Load before DOM is already loaded

Tags: jquery, dom, cookies

Ok guys, I started to learn more about Jquery and now I could make this simple script, which keeps my tabs opened on changing pages, but there's an annoying bug.

The tab opens before my DOM finishes loading, and it looks like weird. So you open a tab in a page and than later, when the next page is fully loaded, the tab opens.

What I want is to keep opened the tab, or at least have it look like the tab is opened.

In the cookie I store the id of the element that I want to show

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cookie = $.cookie("current");
if(cookie != null){

    $("#"+cookie).show()
    $.cookie("current" , null);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am slightly confused as to what you are asking but `$(document).ready()` doesn't run until the DOM has loaded.

If you want to wait for **everything** to load then you can use `$(window).load()` in it's place as this waits for things like images on the page to finish also.

Comment: Ohh noo.. I want to do everything before the visual interface has been loaded.. i'm used to work with Php and now in javascript I can't load things before the text and everything else has benn loaded

Comment: @IstvanNagy You can't run javascript (non server-side) before the DOM starts loading because the DOM has to start loading to call the javascript. At which point the javascript is called depends on many factors such as browser and connection speed. If you want to do this you need to have a page of pure javascript and use the javascript to load the rest of the page when you are ready.